# FOSElasticaBundle to filter out entity with certain property

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

I have setup FOSElasticaBundle that indexes InstagramShopPictures, which has the following property:

```
class InstagramShopPicture
{
     /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @Exclude()
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyApp\MainBundle\Entity\InstagramPictureCategory", mappedBy="picture", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    protected $category;

}
```

How do I specify in elasticsearch (or FOSElasticaBundle) that I want to filter out the results such that only the one that has category of A, where A is a InstagramPictureCategory that the user specifies. Is this possible to filter this out in elastica?

Comment: At which point do you want to do the filtering: when data goes IN to ElasticSearch, or when data is coming out?

Comment: when data is coming out @JustinFinkelstein